# Can we use Knockout JS along with Smarty Templates?

Tags: knockout.js, smarty

Hey I am trying to use Knockout JS . I am relatively new to this framework. I use mootools but found out knockout is interesting and awesome , so just started to play around and had this issue of using smarty variables in html . Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to parse bindings

Comment: can you show us some code, so that we can have a clear understanding of the problem

Answer (score 0):

Smarty is server side, Knockout is client side. So they can't cause any conflicts.

It might look as follows:

```
$smarty->assign('person',  array('name' => 'John doe'));
```

And your template:

```
<div data-bind="text: name"></div>
<script>ko.applyBindings($person|@json_encode});</script>
```